# How to upload modified file without reloading website

Tags: javascript, java

I have a case as follow:

Step 1: Open pop-up, upload file -> Success.

Step 2: Edit file just uploaded.

Step 3: without reload website, reopen pop-up.

Step 4: select file just edited to upload.

Expected result: Upload success.

Actual result  : upload error: Data format of the uploaded file is not EXCEL file.

[image: Actual result]

How i can fix it??
This is my code

Code js

```js
    function handlerUploadFile() {
      var form = $(‘'#uploadFile_action')[@];
      var data = new FormData(form);
      loading_ajax();
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart / form - data ',
            url: '../sac0@12/uploadFile.action',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 620000,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
              close_loading_ajax(
              };
              var messageld = "";
              var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader('content - type ') || °";
                if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
                  showNotifyDialog("fileNotFormatExcel");
                  return; +
                  if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (obj.result == "SUCCESS”) {
                      showNotifyDialog("fileUploadSuccess") $("#myModalUpload”).css("
                        display”, “none ")};
                        $('#itemDetails')
                      }.empty(); loadContent(limit, offset, transactionId, scrollTop);
                    }
                    else {
                      if (obj.code == "EA-0003") {
                        messageId = "EA-0003";
                        contentConfirm = mesSystem[messageId];
                        alert(contentConfirm);
                      } else if (obj.code == "ERROR_PLT_ID_LENGTH") {
                        messageId = "ERROR_PLT_ID_LENGTH";
                        contentConfirm = mesSystem[messageId];
                        alert(contentConfirm);
                      } else {
                        alert("Data format of the uploaded file is not correct.");
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                  close_loading_ajax();
                  alert("Data format of the uploaded file is not EXCEL file.");
                }
              });
          }
```

code jsp

```
<form id="uploadFile_action" name="uploadFile_action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row" style="margin: 5px 0 0; border-bottom: 1px solid gray; height: 40px;">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 file" style="margin-top: 5px; width: auto;">
<b style="font-weight: 900;">Upload File:</b>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9 file-return" contentEditable=false data-text="File path"></div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 input-file-container">
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="false" id="uploadFile_action_confirm" />
<input type="file" name="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" class="input-file" value="" id="uploadFile_action_file" />
<button tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger" value="Browse"><b style="font-weight: 800;">Browse</b></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<p id="emptyFileUpload" style="display: none;"></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger textWhite" id="uploadFile_action_0" style="height: 34px" value="Upload" />
<input type="button" value="Back" class="cancelButton">
</div>
<s:hidden name="transactionId"></s:hidden>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post CODE, not a picture of code - you'll want ro prevent the default form submit action `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: i see that you have put the code and removed the image of code. good.